AP Calculus BC 2024 - Taylor's Inequality/Series Estimation
The free-response questions from this year's AP Calculus BC exam were just released, and I am particularly interested in question 6b. A question of this type appears each year, and I think when I took the exam in 2012, I faltered on the error estimate.

The Maclaurin series for a function $ f $ is given by $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)x^n}{n^2 6^n} $$
and converges to $ f(x) $ for all $ x $ in the interval of convergence. It can be shown that the Maclaurin series for $ f $ has a radius of convergence of 6.


6b. It can be shown that
$$ f(-3) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)(-3)^n}{n^2 6^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n^2} \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^n $$
and that the first three terms of this series sum to $S_3 = -\frac{125}{144}$. Show that
$$ \left| f(-3) - S_3 \right| < \frac{1}{50}. $$

I ask for my attempt to be verified.
The series representation for $f(-3)$ is alternating, so we may use the alternating series estimation theorem. Write:
\begin{align*}
|f(-3) - S_3| &\leq |a_4| \\
& = \left| \frac{4+1}{4^2} \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right) ^{4+1} \right| \\
&= \frac{5}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{32} \\
&= \frac{5}{512} \\
& < \frac{1}{50}
\end{align*}
as needed.
Even as somebody that as served as teaching assistant for calculus II for a good while, these sort of problems always cause me to pause. Is this solution sound for an AP exam? In particular, have I used the alternating series estimation theorem correctly to bound the error? For a bonus, can the bound be strengthened in any way?

This looks fine to me, and is all that can be realistically done. Although one can solve for the power series as the sum of a log and an inexplicit antiderivative, this doesn’t help.
